# Clever alternative to mysql full text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

#### Table1

- ID    INT
- Tags  TEXT

#### Table2

- ID    INT
- Tags  TEXT

The tags field could look like this `"abc def hij 123"`. Tags being space delimited. Each record could have in excess of 200 tags. (Tags are being defined "on the fly" )

Given a record from table1 I want to find the "most suitable" record from table2 where the tags in the row from table1 match tags in row from table2.

MySQL FULL text search seems like the best thing to use for this.

Table2 should only have around 800-1000 rows - so not much overhead there. But Table1 might have 20 million, and I may want to, in the future, do the reverse (find best match from table1 for a row in table2).

#### Question:

Do you think FULL TEXT search is the best thing to use here?  If not what would could be an alternative?

I have looked into XML databases, and they promising (especially Xbase)...  but do I feel confident to put that database live on a production machine? Not yet... (or should I?)

Comment: Your tags are denormalized data, which makes a lot of operations difficult (number of a particular tag, stopping duplicates, etc).  Full Text Search should not be on your radar yet.

Comment: @OMG_Ponies I think we could prevent duplicates and ensure only one tag of each type before adding the tag itself. Would that change things?

Comment: It looks that FULL TEXT is your only option, since the fields of your table are only ID and Tags, there is nothing you can do, for example you can not create an index based in your ID, because there are no match point in your table2.

Comment: If you're going with separate tags, you should structure the data correctly as OMG Ponies suggests.  If it turns out that you have the need to compare hundreds of tags over 20 millions records very, very quickly you will need another solution — but it will some kind of precomputation (to be determined based on the nature of the data) and not storing the individual tags.

Comment: Full text doesn't address words less than 3 characters, and have you considered false positives (portions of the text occurring in tags you didn't want to be matched)?  There is no string matching approach that works -- tags need to be separated by rows.

Comment: Off-topic: @BlakeKPeterson I've done some work on your PHP encryption function in Objective-C, but the question has been deleted. If you want an answer, post it again (maybe worded differently to avoid it being closed) and I will save it and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full text search will not help you because neither your needle *nor* your haystack are normalized.  If you had only a single tag (the needle) to search for in a de-normalized list (the haystack), FTS could help you.  But, instead, you need to first normalize the list of search tags into a bunch of separate needles, then search for each one in the haystack.

You're much better off just normalizing the data in the first place (separate tag tables of the form (ID, Tag)) and using JOIN to determine how many points of commonality there are.

**On further consideration** I would suggest a single TaggedItems table, with a structure like this: `(TAG TEXT(3), ID1 INTEGER, ID2 INTEGER)`.  When you want to tag table 1 you would issue an INSERT OR UPDATE (or MySQL equivalent) for the tag and the ID1 column.  The same for table 2 and the ID2 column.  Now, you can retrieve a similarity rating by selecting the count of records in this table where ID1 = the ID1 value you're interested in and ID2 is NOT NULL, GROUPed BY ID2.  No JOIN required.

Comment: Thanks.. if there were 200 tags - would that not mean 200 joins?

Comment: No, one JOIN between the table with the tags for Table1 and the table with the tags for Table2 (which could be a SELF JOIN using the same table for both depending on how you set up the database.  Actually, if there are only two tables, it strikes me you could use a clever design to even avoid the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You could have another table expressing the relation between ID and each individual word "aaa" "bbb" ...

Comment: Yeah, that's where the XML database idea came from. It would be more flexible than having relationship tables. But yes. relationship tables are an option. But trying to get the best match... might be crazy.